# use v-model for generated input tag

Tags: vue.js

I'm developing a quiz maker app with Vue and I want to show some generated input element on page which are bound to data model. But after generating the input tag in computed region, when I change the input nothing is bound to model.

```
<%--in html file--%>
<span v-html="currentQuestion.splitedTitle"></span>

splitedTitle: function() {
            var split = this.currentQuestion.title.split('$');
            var result = '';
            var order = vm.currentQuestion.questionOrder;
            for (let i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                const splitElement = split[i];
                result += splitElement;
                var inputElement = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-in-text" :class="isFillInTheBlanksAnswerTrue('+ i +')" ' +
                    'v-model="answers['+ order +'].choice['+i+']" onchange="vm.inputChanged()"/>';
                if (i < split.length - 1) {
                    result += inputElement;
                }
            }
            return result;
        },
```

I'll be appreciated if you tell me what to do.

Comment: `v-html` is for HTML only, you can't pass it Vue template syntax. At first glance it would seem that you just need to move the input creation into the template and use the computed property to create an array suitable for use with `v-for`.

Comment: when I use the code below, it generates some span that ruins output by generating extra span tag and then browsers considers them as a unclosed tag and tries to close them automatically. 
`code`
<span v-for="(sq, index) in splitedQuestion">
    <span v-html="sq"></span>
    <input v-if="index < splitedQuestion.length - 1"  v-model="answers[currentQuestion.questionOrder].choice[index]"
                           type="text" class="form-control"  />
</span>
`

Answer (score 0):

Vue template ≠ HTML; you're using `v-html` with a Vue template string which will not work.

If you need to dynamically generate elements in your component's template then you need to do this by building a model of the UI you want to display in code and then rendering it out in the template with `v-for`, `<component>`, etc; or for more complex UI you might need to write the [render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) by hand.